# Offset independent hash function

Tags: arrays, algorithm, hash

Is there any hash function that generates the same bucket for vectors having the same elements, with the same relative positions but shifted **k** times?

For example:

```
hash([1,9,8,7]) -> b1
hash([9,8,7,1]) -> b1

hash([1,8,9,7]) -> b2
hash([1,9,8,5]) -> b3
```

**v1** = [1,9,8,7] **v2** = [9,8,7,1] Both vectors should get the same hash since **v2** is **v1** left shifted k=3 times.

But **v3** = [1,8,9,7] doesn't keep the same relative order and **v4** = [1,9,8,5] has different values so neither of them get the hash b1.

My initial approach was to calculte the max value for each vector and consider its position as a reference (offset = 0). Having that I would only have to shift each vector so that the maximun value would be always at the first position. This way shifted vectors would look the same. However, vectors can have repeated elements and thus the maximun value has different positions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Find the lexicographically minimal array rotation.

   The native way is to check all rotations in O(n<sup>2</sup>), but it can be done in linear time using Booth's Algorithm, Shiloach's Fast Canonization Algorithm or Duval's Lyndon Factorization Algorithm.

   See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographically_minimal_string_rotation) for more.
2. Calculate the hash of the rotated array.

   This can be done in various ways. Java, for example, would do it as follows:

   ```
   hash = s[0]*31^(n-1) + s[1]*31^(n-2) + ... + s[n-1]
   ```

It's not impossible that arrays with different elements will hash to the same value (this is inevitable with hashing), but all rotations of the same array will have the same hash.

Answer (score 1):

If we concatenated b1 with itself then we get:

`[1,9,8,7,1,9,8,7]`

This array contains all cyclic permutations of the original array.

If we then calculate a hash for every subarray of length 4 and join and combine these, you will have a unique hash. The hash function calculation may require some optimizing, depending on the size of your arrays.

EDIT: every subarray, except for the last, which equals the first!

Comment: It is not necessary to concatenate the vector with itself, just iterate from each vector position in a circular way, that would provide the same result without doubling the memory use. I think your solution is formally correct but If I am not wrong and assuming each subarray hash calculation being O(n) [n=4 in this example] your method has at least O(n^2) time complexity. I wonder if it could be improved.

Comment: It depends on the calculation of the hash function: say h(k) = a0 + a1 k^1 + a2 k^2 + ... then we might calculate h of the second permutation from that of the previous one with a constant number of operations. So h(1,9,8,7) could be reused to calculate h(9,8,7,1), we could reuse the 9,8,7 part (divide it by k).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not care so much about the occasional hash collision, you could simply take the sum of all the elements as a hash (but be careful of floating point issues), since that is invariant to any rotation of the vector. Alternatively, you could `xor` or sum all the hashes of the individual elements. You could also calculate something based on the difference of subsequent elements (while wrapping around for the last to the first element). Add a few of these properties that are invariant to rotation together and the chance that two 'unequal' arrays will yield the same hash will be pretty low. Maybe something like

```
n = length(x)
rot_invariant_hash = hash(n) + sum(hash(x[i])) + sum(hash(x[mod(i+1, n)] - x[i]))
```

where you can replace all the sums for any other commutative (?) operation like XOR. Also make sure that the hash-function applied on the differences is not the identity function, or these parts will all add up to zero. All this takes O(n) computation time.

Just a curiosity: what is your intended application?

Comment: I am trying to develop a hash function for cyclic polygons. Hence, the input vectors are the relative distances of different nodes in the circumscribed circle.

Comment: None (to the OP): if you need to do a final compare (after the hash) you'll have to get your cyclic polygons into some canonical form anyway.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that you always have numbers as vector components, compute:

- the product of all components
- the product of all differences `d_i` of neighboring components (`i`, `(i+1) mod n`),
  where 1 is added for all non-negative differences

and multiply both.

the first product abstracts away from the order of the elements, which is re-introduced by the second product modulo component rotation. adding 1 to each difference avoids mapping to 0 if there are 2 adjacent components of the same value.

the standalone first product does not suffice, as it maps all component permutations to the same hash value.
the standalone second product does not suffice, as it maps all vectors offset along (1,...,1) to the same value.

Comment: I'll try this solution but I have an observation: If to consecutive elements are equal, the product of all differences of neighboring components is zero so I think it should be the product of all the differences plus and offset of the same sign than the difference itself.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo: good point, thanks. answer adjusted.

Answer (score 1):

Don't hash the elements of the array, hash the differences of two adjacent cells instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned hashdiff(unsigned arr[], size_t siz);

        /* toy hash function: don't try this at home ... */
#define HASH1(v) ((v)*7654321)

unsigned hashdiff(unsigned arr[], size_t siz)
{
unsigned idx;
unsigned hash;

if (siz < 1) return 0;
if (siz < 2) return HASH1(arr[0]);

hash = HASH1( arr[0] - arr[siz-1] );

for(idx=1; idx < siz; idx++) {
        hash ^= HASH1(arr[idx] - arr[idx-1] );
        }

return hash;
}

unsigned arr1[] = {1,9,8,7};
unsigned arr2[] = {9,8,7,1 };

unsigned arr3[] = {1,8,9,7 };
unsigned arr4[] = {1,9,8,5 };

int main(void)
{
unsigned hash;

hash = hashdiff (arr1, 4); printf("%x\n", hash);
hash = hashdiff (arr2, 4); printf("%x\n", hash);
hash = hashdiff (arr3, 4); printf("%x\n", hash);
hash = hashdiff (arr4, 4); printf("%x\n", hash);

return 0;
}
```

RESULT:

```
./a.out
fee56452
fee56452
1100b22
fca02416
```

UPDATE: if you don't want {1,2,3,4} and{11,12,13,14} to hash to the same value, you could augment the difference like this:

```
#define HASH1(v) ((v)*7654321)
#define HASH2(a,b) HASH1(3u*(a)-5u*(b))

unsigned hashdiff2(unsigned arr[], size_t siz)
{
unsigned idx;
unsigned hash;

if (siz < 1) return 0;
if (siz < 2) return HASH1(arr[0]);

hash = HASH2( arr[0] , arr[siz-1] );

for(idx=1; idx < siz; idx++) {
        hash ^= HASH2( arr[idx] , arr[idx-1] );
        }

return hash;
}
```

Comment: This would hash [1,2,3,4] and [11,12,13,14] to the same value.

Comment: Collisions are a fact of life! You could use another non-communative operator/function instead of substraction.

Comment: I know, but you probably want to avoid a collision for a pretty common case.

Comment: BTW in the case of an array of vectors representing a polygon, the collisions would mean a translation-invariant hash function. It's a feature, not a bug!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I have not coded it, but I think it could work:

To get your hash you just need to capture the order of the items, and avoid the offset. Sort the items like this:

```
a = [1,9,8,7]
s = sort(a) = [1,7,8,9]
```

Now capture the order between them:

```
1 => 9
7 => 1
8 => 7
9 => 8

snext = next(s, a) = [9,1,7,8]
```

Now concat s and snext:

```
[1,7,8,9,9,1,7,8]
```

And hash it.

To implement next() function just use vector a as an associative array and iterate through s items.

The array [9,8,7,1] would yield same hash because it shares the same items and their relative order is equal.

Nevertheless, array [1,8,9,7] yields a different hash; it shares the same items but their relative order is not the same.

I hope it helps.